# fatal exception main sql database

Tags: android

i want to make a app, but when i run, the logcat shows:FATAL EXCEPTION MAIN

**CODE:**

```
package com.example.mythirdapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       SQLiteDatabase pf;

       TableRow tablerow;
       TextView t,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5;    
       String first_name,last_name;
       String userGender; 


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pf=openOrCreateDatabase("Profile",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        pf.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Persone(first_name VARCHAR,last_name VARCHAR,userGender VARCHAR);");
    }


    public void add(View view){
        EditText fn  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first_name);
        EditText ln   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.last_name);

        first_name=fn.getText().toString();
        last_name =ln.getText().toString();

        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio_female:
                if (checked)
                    userGender = "female";
                break;
            case R.id.radio_male:
                if (checked)
                   userGender = "male";
                break;
        }

        pf.execSQL("INSERT INTO Persone VALUES('"+first_name+"','"+last_name+"','"+userGender+"');");
    }



    public void show(View view){
        Cursor c = pf.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Persone", null);
        int count = c.getCount();
        c.moveToFirst();
        TableLayout tablelayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
        tablelayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        TableRow tablerow;
        TextView t,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5;
        tablerow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

        t = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        t.setText("First Name");
        t.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        t.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
        t.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
        tablerow.addView(t);

        t3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        t3.setText("Last Name");
        t3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        t3.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
        t3.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
        tablerow.addView(t3);

        t4 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        t4.setText("Gender");
        t4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        t4.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
        t4.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
        tablerow.addView(t4);

        tablelayout.addView(tablerow);
        for(Integer j = 0;j<count;j++)
        {
          tablerow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

          t1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
          t1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("first_name")));
          t1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);


          t2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
          t2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("last_name")));
          t2.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

          t5 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
          t5.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("userGender")));
          t5.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);



          tablerow.addView(t1);
          tablerow.addView(t2);
          tablerow.addView(t5);


          tablelayout.addView(tablerow);

          c.moveToNext();
        }
        setContentView(tablelayout);
        pf.close();
    }
}
```

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mythirdapp.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/last_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/first_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/first_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:onClick="add"
        android:text="@string/add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/last_name"
        android:onClick="show"
        android:text="@string/show" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/last_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/first_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/last_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/gender"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_gender"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_female"
            android:text="@string/radio_female"
            android:onClick="add" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_male"
            android:text="@string/radio_male" 
            android:onClick="add"/>

    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

than logcat

```
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854): Process: com.example.mythirdapp, PID: 854
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  ... 11 more
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at com.example.mythirdapp.MainActivity.add(MainActivity.java:46)
10-02 10:25:55.156: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  ... 14 more
```

i think it is the settext problem, but i don't know why.
i want to add text into the sql.
but when it comes to add gender, it goes wrong

Comment: Please post more info from the LogCat so we can see where excatly the exception is thrown.

Comment: post logcat for the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you problem is here

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:onClick="add"
        android:text="@string/add" />
```

exactly here `android:onClick="add"`
in that `add(View view)` method you are casting View view to RadioButton,

```
boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
```

sometimes it will be Button, as you have declared onClick for the button as "add" too

thats why you have this exception

```
ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton
```

so either you fix this by checking what the view is instance of, or declare another method for the Button

Comment: sorry i don't queitly understand. do you mean i should change the name of the onclick name's, one is "add",one is "another".and then in the mainactivity, i should create  public void add(){} and public void another(){}.....?

Comment: Yes thats what you have to do

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. I don't know how you have implemented your layout but assuming it to be the simplest : with two editTexts, Two radioButtons and one button to show the result. Here's how i implemented the things.

**MainActivity.class**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    SQLiteDatabase pf;

TableRow tablerow;
TextView t, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5;
String first_name, last_name;
String userGender;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pf = openOrCreateDatabase("Profile", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    pf.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Persone(first_name VARCHAR,last_name VARCHAR,userGender VARCHAR);");
}

public void add(View view)
{
    EditText fn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_name);
    EditText ln = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.last_name);

    first_name = fn.getText().toString();
    last_name = ln.getText().toString();

    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.radio_female:
            if (checked)
                userGender = "female";
            break;
        case R.id.radio_male:
            if (checked)
                userGender = "male";
            break;
    }

    pf.execSQL("INSERT INTO Persone VALUES('" + first_name + "','" + last_name + "','" + userGender + "');");
}

public void show(View view)
{
    Cursor c = pf.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Persone", null);
    int count = c.getCount();
    c.moveToFirst();
    TableLayout tablelayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
    tablelayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    TableRow tablerow;
    TextView t, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5;
    tablerow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

    t = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    t.setText("First Name");
    t.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    t.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    t.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    tablerow.addView(t);

    t3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    t3.setText("Last Name");
    t3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    t3.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    t3.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    tablerow.addView(t3);

    t4 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    t4.setText("Gender");
    t4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    t4.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    t4.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    tablerow.addView(t4);

    tablelayout.addView(tablerow);
    for (Integer j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        tablerow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

        t1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        t1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("first_name")));
        t1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

        t2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        t2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("last_name")));
        t2.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

        t5 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        t5.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("userGender")));
        t5.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

        tablerow.addView(t1);
        tablerow.addView(t2);
        tablerow.addView(t5);

        tablelayout.addView(tablerow);

        c.moveToNext();
    }
    setContentView(tablelayout);
    pf.close();
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.stackoverflow_1.MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/first_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/last_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_female"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="add"
    android:text="Female" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_male"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="add"
    android:text="Male" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="show"
    android:text="Show" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i add a RadioGroup also, does it matter?

Comment: @JiYicheng no RadioGroup won't affect anything... yeah it works on my computer... yours still not working...??

Comment: @JiYicheng the new edit in your post suggest that you must have used a button to add the details, When you're clicking that button the button object is being passed as an argument to add method in your java file and definitely you can't convert a button to radioButton...
Either use onClick attribute in both of the radioButtons (which i'm currently doing) or simple set onClickListner to the button in the java file.